# Resolving database connectivity issues on Forge

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

When I try to login to the app I have setup on Forge, my Laravel app spits out this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'appname'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have the environment variables configured correctly and they work fine on my copy of the site on my local Homestead vagrant box.

Here is the .env.php file that Forge wrote:

```
return [
    'APP_ENV'   => 'production',
    'DB_DRIVER' => 'mysql',
    'DB_HOST'   => 'localhost',
    'DB_NAME'   => 'appname',
    'DB_USER'   => 'appname',
    'DB_PASS'   => 'LoNgPaSsWoRd',
];
```

Here is the relevant contents of `app/config/database.php` which works locally:

```
'default' => getenv('DB_DRIVER'),

'connections' => array(

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => getenv('DB_DRIVER'),
        'host'      => getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'database'  => getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'username'  => getenv('DB_USER'),
        'password'  => getenv('DB_PASS'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

),
```

I tried dumping the environment values before the first database connection is accessed using `dd(getenv('DB_PASS'), getenv('DB_USER'))` and they show up correct.

I also tried connecting through MySQL Workbench and resetting the password to exactly what is shown in the environment variable Forge wrote.

None of my other subdomains are having this issue.

What could be going on here and how could I debug this?